# declaring as row of a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I will first show my code and then i'll explain what's wrong:

```
$sql_result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM account_information WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    $about=$row['about'];

echo'<table>';
echo
<<<EOT
  <form action="profile.php" method="post">
  <textarea name="about" rows="5" cols="50" >{$about}</textarea> 
  <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></td>
  </form>

EOT;
echo'</table>';

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
        $about = $_POST['about'];
                    $sql_result2 = $mysqli->query("update account_information SET about='".$about."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
        $edit=false;
        echo "<div id='about'>".$about."</div>";
}
}
```

Now as you can see when you type something in the textarea, it should go into my database(which it does) and when I come on the page again I want the text to be shown. The code: `$about=$row['about'];` should do that. Which it doesn't I cant seem to find the problem to this. In the beginning it just doesn't show anything which it should(the previous entry of the textarea saved in the database) What should I do? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your submit code outside of the while loop and above the select query.

```
$about = '';
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
    $about = $_POST['about'];
    $sql_result2 = $mysqli->query("update account_information SET about='".$about."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
    $edit=false;
    echo "<div id='about'>".$about."</div>";
}

$sql_result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM account_information WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
```

and so on ....

As in your code you are taking first the old value from the database and then put again this in the database. that replacing the code new code and the text entered by you in the textarea. So you need to first save it in the database and then fetch that to get the updated text.

Comment: This is kind of a pain to do because I do need the while loop in the header and the submit stuff etc in the middle and when I put it above the while, I get mysql errors.

Comment: I fixed the error but the solution you told me isn't working.

Comment: @loko I hope this will work because this is logically right way.

Comment: Can't I just chat with you in a chatroom about this? that's easier. So I can show you all of my code.

Comment: @loko yah sure this will be helpful to me to provide a proper the solution to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37869/discussion-between-loko-and-broken-heart-)

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's a bit hard for the script to tell that value is updated until before it is, so I would use this:

```
  $sql_result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM account_information WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    $about= isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['about'] : $row['about'];

echo'<table>';
echo
<<<EOT
  <form action="profile.php" method="post">
  <textarea name="about" rows="5" cols="50" >{$about}</textarea> 
  <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></td>
  </form>

EOT;
echo'</table>';

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
                    $sql_result2 = $mysqli->query("update account_information SET about='".$about."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
        $edit=false;
        echo "<div id='about'>".$about."</div>";
}
}
```